# How to match this expression with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a text with some lines (200+) in this format:

```
10684 - The jackpot ? discuss   Lev 3    --- ? ---

10755 - Garbage Heap    ? discuss   Lev 5    --- ? ---
```

I hant to retrieve the first number (10684 or 10755) only if number after "Lev" is greater than 3.
I'm able to get the first number with this regex: `([0-9]+) -` but without the 'level' restrictions.

How this could be made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this task is suitable for RegExp though... Is the number after Lev always less than 10?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions doesn't recognize numbers as numbers (only strings). You can do this though:

```
([0-9]+) - .*Lev (?:[4-9][^0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)
```

Basically, we use the **alternation** operator (`|`) to accept only a single digit greater than 3 (enforced by checking that the *following* character is *not* a digit) or a multi-digit number not beginning with a zero.

In case that level number might be the end of the line, though, you might have to do this:

```
([0-9]+) - .*Lev (?:[4-9](?:[^0-9]|$)|[1-9][0-9]+)
```

(I'm assuming whatever regex engine you're using can't handle lookaround assertions. In the future, try to always include what language you're using when you're asking a regex question.)

---

Ah, I just read your edit that the number is always less than 10. Well, that's much easier then:

```
([0-9]+) - .*Lev [4-9]
```

Answer (score 3):

`(\d+) - .*?Lev (?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)`

The first `\d+` matches line number as you have done.

The next `.*?` is a lazy quantifier, which will not consume too many characters. And the  following expression will guide it to the right place. (lazy quantifier is usually more efficient)

The second parenthesis, `(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)`, matches either single digital numbers greater than 3 or two digital numbers without leading zero.

Alright stackoverflow doesn't properly show my image. Take this link : http://regexr.com?36n5l

Example Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually, your solution is cleaner than mine. I've been bitten by the "forgot-to-check-digits-that-follow" mistake so many times that I automatically check, but any number beginning with `[4-9]` is necessarily larger than 3, so there's no need for my `[^0-9]`. +1.

Comment: Don't forget about `04`?

Answer (score 0):

A lookahead is really the best thing because it will leave just the number:

```
/\d+(?=.*Lev (0*[4-9]|[1-9]\d))/
```

Comment: Yep. And you can shorten your solution to `/\d+(?=.*Lev [4-9])/`

Comment: Only if we assume < 10

Comment: See the info from the comments :)

Comment: I see it. Obviously matching a single digit number is simple but that wasn't the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Awk trickery:

```
awk -F '\? +discuss +Lev' '$2>3 { split($1,a,/ */); print a[1] }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash use this:

```
var=">3"
perl -lne '/(\d+) - .*Lev (\d+)/; print $1 if $2'"$var"
```

This is a good solution to be able to pass the condition by parameter.